# Why am I having this issue with the tan() function on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, trigonometry

This is my first time building an iOS project using any kind of advanced math. I have searched for quite a while but have yet to find anything to fix my problem. I am still quite new to iOS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to use a basic `tan()` function that takes an input from a textfield, turns it into degrees (because tan() defaults to radians) and displays in a label. If I was to input tan 30 into a calculator it would return .577, I am getting .449, which is close but if I input 31, i receive a value of "2.356"?

Here is the part of my code:

```
-(IBAction)calculate {
float x = ([textField1.text intValue]);
float d = (x * 180) / M_PI;
float y = tan(d);


label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.3f", y];
}
```

Comment: First, Xcode is just an IDE, not a framework or a platform. The math functions are provided by the system, not Xcode itself, and are standard C ones. Second, the C `tan()` function takes in radians, and you appear to be converting your input from radians to degrees. I think you have that backwards (you need to multiply by pi and divide by 180.0 instead of the other way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string you're using (`%2.f`) is inappropriate for the data -- it's specifying that no decimal places should be displayed. Try just using `%f`.

Comment: yeah i just realised i typed that wrong. i changed to 2.3  I just changed original post but i Am still getting strange outputs, thanks

Comment: It was a case of radians, and doing the math wrong trying to work out the decimals. Brad larson did answer, but it was in a comment.
First, Xcode is just an IDE, not a framework or a platform. The math functions are provided by the system, not Xcode itself, and are standard C ones. Second, the C tan() function takes in radians, and you appear to be converting your input from radians to degrees. I think you have that backwards (you need to multiply by pi and divide by 180.0 instead of the other way around). – Brad Larson Apr 30 at 1:04

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction)calculate {
float x = textField1.text.doubleValue;
float d = (x * 180) / M_PI;
float y = tan(d);

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f", y];
```

Answer (score 0):

your "d" is a float. Try using tanf() instead of tan().

Comment: thanks for the feedback all but its still returning the same value's